# Possible Bug during Editing Question or Answer

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, error-message

I noticed that when we try to edit a **Question or Answer** with a lot of code and less description, upon submitting, we get the error:

> It looks like your answer is mostly code; please add some more details.

However, editing guidelines also ask us to:

> Always respect the original author.

This means that we *should not* make changed to the author's code. However, if the question/answer *already* has a lot of code, we get the above stated error, and remain unable to edit such questions.

I guess, Stack Overflow should use separate validations for editing of questions/answers.

Comment: Which question were you trying to edit?

Comment: @BilltheLizard This one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790004/validate-my-htmk-form-field-after-my-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: Hmmm... that OP should have gotten the same error message you did. It's weird that they can submit that question but you can't edit it. I think that's the bug here.

Comment: @BilltheLizard However, I always get the error when trying to post a question with mostly code! Weird!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the two messages you quoted are directly opposed to each other. There are more things in a post that can be edited other than code, so the "It looks like your answer is mostly code; please add some more details." message isn't really stopping you from making an edit, it's just stopping you from making the kinds of edits that don't fix the major problem with this question.

While you certainly shouldn't edit code in a question (because you might inadvertently change what was causing the problem to begin with), other elements could be *added* that will change the code/text balance. In [the specific case you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29790004/1288) (as in many cases), those are changes that are best left to the original poster of the question.

In short, I think that message is telling you that small edits to spelling and grammar are not enough to warrant an edit to a question that has bigger problems.

Comment: However, one would have to put in a large number of extra words to remove that error, which would of course we kinda senseless.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Right, which is why I say it's really up to the original poster to fix that question. They're the only one who can really either reduce the code or increase the explanation of the code to a sufficient degree to make a good edit.

Comment: But, the thing is still where it was. How did the original author get past that error and post that *mostly code* question?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi I'm not sure. That question isn't so old that the rules have changes since then, so my guess is that the rules are just different for posting an initial question vs. editing an existing one. The error dialog may just be a warning when posting a new question.